# Json Data not updating

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am removing a row from an angularjs table using this code:

```
$scope.removeRow = function (index) {
if (index === -1) {
alert("Something gone wrong");
}else{
$scope.budgetdetails.splice(index,1);
}
```

However my json data and database are not updating. What do I need to do to update the data in both of them?

Comment: Need to send that information to server using `$http` and server would update database. In order to do that you need to pass in whole object to your function so you have id to send ... then  index it yourself

Comment: Thank you charlieftl. I was reading about that. Is there a good example you could point me to?

Comment: this will help. use it inside your ajax promise callback http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click/15454424#15454424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. I followed this tutorial

[Angular-js-with-ASP-NET-MVC-Insert-Update-Delete](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034593/Angular-js-with-ASP-NET-MVC-Insert-Update-Delete)

Answer (score 0):

smth like this: [Auto select and collect checkbox values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131240/auto-select-and-collect-checkbox-values-in-array/38132708#38132708)

```
$scope.getData = function(Day) {
var index = $scope.budgetdetails.indexOf(Day);

if (index < 0) {
  $scope.budgetdetails.push(Day)
  console.log('myData', $scope.budgetdetails);
} else {
  $scope.budgetdetails.splice(index, 1)
  console.log('myData',$scope.budgetdetails);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Prianca, this code removes the row from my angular table. However bottom-line it does the same my code was doing. My json is still not updating and the rows in my database remain the same. Mansa suggested to use $http for that. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To update in database,  you need to use $http service (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http ) and your Api should handle this code .

```
 $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '//http://localhost/MyAPI/MyRoute',
      data    : $scope.budgetdetails, //forms user object
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
     })
      .success(function(data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          // Showing errors.            
        } else { //success message for API
          $scope.message = data.message;
        }
      }
```